# Change spell checking from UK to US English

Tags: release-juno, language

The system spell checking on my installation of elementary OS (Juno) is set to UK English (e.g. "organise", instead of "organize"), perhaps because I installed it while I was outside of the US. I have changed the language on my account to US English and logged out and back in, but the spell-checker is still set to UK English. How can I change the spell-checking language?